# Changing the value of an @Bean at runtime in Java Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, datasource

In `Java` with `Spring Boot` framework there is an `@Bean` named `DataSource` that is used to make connections to a database, and is used by another `@Bean` called `JdbcTemplate` that serves to perform actions on the database. But, there is a problem, this `@Bean` `DataSource`, which serves to make the connection to the database, requires the properties for the connection to be preconfigured (url, username and password). The `@Bean` `DataSource` needs to start with an "empty" or "default" value at project startup, and at runtime it changes this value. I want a certain Endpoint to execute the action of changing the value of `@Bean`, to be more exact. And with the change of the value of the `@Bean` `DataSource` the `JdbcTemplate`, consequently, will be able to perform actions in several database.

Some details:

- I have already evaluated this issue of using multiple databases, and in my case, it will be necessary.
- All databases to be connected have the same model.
- I do not think I need to delete and create another `@Bean` `DataSource` at runtime, maybe just override the `@Bean` values ​​that the Spring Boot itself already creates automatically.
- I have already made the `@Bean` `DataSource` start with an "empty" value by making a method with the `@Bean` annotation and that returns a `DataSource` object that is literally this code: `DataSourceBuilder.build().create();`.
- My English is not very good so if it's not very understandable, sorry.

`DataSource` `@Bean` code:

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}
```

Main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "br.com.b2code")
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
public class RunAdm extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements 
CommandLineRunner {

    public static final String URL_FRONTEND = "*";


    /**
     * Método main do módulo de Gestão.
     *
     * @param args argumentos de inicialização
     * @throws Exception uma exception genérica
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(RunAdm.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder 
    configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(RunAdm.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    }

}
```

A class to exemplify how I use `JdbcTemplate`:

```
@Repository
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
public class ClienteQueryRepositoryImpl implements ClienteQueryRepository {

    private final @NonNull
    JdbcTemplate jdbc;

    @Override
    public List<Cliente> findAll() {
        return jdbc.query(ClienteQuerySQL.SELECT_ALL_CLIENTE_SQL, new ClienteRowMapper());
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you please explain the purpose as to why you want to be able to do this?

Comment: @ThomasAndolf My system has to be multi-tenancy with multiple databases that can not be preconfigured, and this was this I found it to do this.
:v

Comment: yes but why can't they be preconfigured?

Comment: @ThomasAndolf because an order from above called for it, it was planned to be so.

Answer (score 0):

I think as a general approach you might consider a Proxy Design Pattern for the actual DataSource Implementation.

Let's suppose the `DataSource` is an interface that has `getConnection` method by user and password (other methods are not really important because this answer is theoretical):

```
interface DataSource {
   Connection getConnection(String user, String password);
}
```

Now, in order to maintain many databases you might want to provide an implementation of the datasource which will act as a proxy for other datasources that will be created on the fly (upon the endpoint call as you say).

Here is an example:

```
public class MultiDBDatasource implements DataSource {
    private DataSourcesRegistry registry;

    public Connection getConnection(String user, String password) {
        UserAndPassword userAndPassword = new UserAndPassword(user, password);

        registry.get(userAndPassword);
    }
}


@Component
class DataSourcesRegistry {
   private Map<UserAndPassword, DataSource> map = ...
   public DataSource get(UserAndPassword a)  { 
         map.get(a); 
   }


   public void addDataSource(UserAndPassword cred, DataSource ds) {
      // add to Map 
      map.put(...)
   }
}


@Controller
class InvocationEndPoint {

    // injected by spring
    private DataSourcesRegistry registry;

    @PostMapping ... 
    public void addNewDB(params) {
         DataSource ds = createDS(params); // not spring based 
         UserAndPassword cred = createCred(params);
         registry.addDataSource(cred, ds);
    } 

}
```

A couple of notes:

1. You should "override" the bean of DataSource offered by spring - this can be done by defining your own bean with the same name in your own configuration that will take precedence over spring's definition.
2. Spring won't create Dynamic Data Source, they'll be created from the "invocation point" (controller in this case for brevity, in real life probably some service). in any case only Registry will be managed by spring, not the data sources.

   3. Keep in mind that this approach is very high-level, in a real life you'll have to think about:

      - Connection Pooling
      - Metering
      - Transaction Support
      - Multithreaded Access 
        and many other things